# Host database using Android phone

Tags: java, android, sqlite, networking

#### Here is the current scenario:

- I have **two(2) Android phones.**

  1. Android Phone 1 as the **server** phone.
  2. Android Phone 2 as the **client** phone.

#### Here is what I want to do:

- I want to create an **Android-based app** (E.g. Student Information app) where it will have basically two (2) modes:

  1. **Server** - for **adding**, **editing** and **deleting** data on a ***local database.***
  2. **Client** - for **viewing** data from the database of the **server**.

The app will be installed to Android Phone 1 and set to Server mode.
The app will be installed to Android Phone 2 and set to Client mode.

#### I want to ask these questions:

1. I want to **locally host** the **database** of the **Server app**, so that **Client app** will be able to view the data. Is this possible?
2. If yes, how can I do it?

**Note:**

1. I am currently a web developer so I know that connected on the **same network** is a requirement.
2. I have implemented the same concept on a medium business where the web-based system is locally hosted so that computers on the same network can access it.
3. Suggest **everything** that you want to suggest, **except** the **disadvantage of doing this concept**. I am aware of some obvious disadvantages based from my research and willing to face the disadvantages provided that I will be able to implement the concept.
4. **Rooting the phones is an option.**
5. I want to **accommodate small-sized business** that is why I want to use **Android phones** **rather** than using **Desktop Computers/Laptop**.

#### I have read similar suggested questions here based on my title.

Answer (score 0):

We have done the exact same thing in my company. The way we solved this is that the server exposes a service using the Android NSD API, so the clients (using the same API) can find it on the network. And after a client has connected to the server, the server sends its database file (yes, the .db file in `/data/data/..`.) to the client via OutputStream. When the client receives the entire database and checks for its integrity, it copies it to its own `/data/data/...` and restarts part of the app.
[Android NSD](https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html)